# Ползунки диапазона

Tags: javascript, jquery

Что-то не могу сообразить. У меня фон позунка (тот что синий) не доходит до начала или вылазит за ползунки по мере их изменения. Если я в min у <input type="range" min="300" выставляю 0, то проблем нету, но у меня могут быть разные диапазоны хоть от 0 до 100, хоть от 1200 до 4000 и т.д. И никак не получается настроить фон диапазона, чтобы был строго в пределах чисел (короче, чтобы работал). *Чтобы было видно о чем говорю откройте код во весь экран.*

```js
window.onload = function(){
    slideOne();
    slideTwo();
}

let sliderOne = document.getElementById("slider-1");
let sliderTwo = document.getElementById("slider-2");
let displayValOne = document.getElementById("range1");
let displayValTwo = document.getElementById("range2");
let minGap = 0;
let sliderTrack = document.querySelector(".slider-track");
let sliderMaxValue = document.getElementById("slider-1").max;

function slideOne(){
    if(parseInt(sliderTwo.value) - parseInt(sliderOne.value) <= minGap){
        sliderOne.value = parseInt(sliderTwo.value) - minGap;
    }
    displayValOne.textContent = sliderOne.value;
    fillColor();
}
function slideTwo(){
    if(parseInt(sliderTwo.value) - parseInt(sliderOne.value) <= minGap){
        sliderTwo.value = parseInt(sliderOne.value) + minGap;
    }
    displayValTwo.textContent = sliderTwo.value;
    fillColor();
}
function fillColor(){
    percent1 = (sliderOne.value / sliderMaxValue) * 100;
    percent2 = (sliderTwo.value / sliderMaxValue) * 100;
    sliderTrack.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #dadae5 ${percent1}% , #3264fe ${percent1}% , #3264fe ${percent2}%, #dadae5 ${percent2}%)`;
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
}
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    background-color: #000;
    place-items: center;
}
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 95vmin;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 50px 40px 20px 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
input[type="range"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slider-track{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 5px;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track{
    -moz-appearance: none;
    height: 5px;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-track{
    appearance: none;
    height: 5px;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1.7em;
    width: 1.7em;
    background-color: #3264fe;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -9px;
    pointer-events: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1.7em;
    width: 1.7em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #3264fe;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb{
    appearance: none;
    height: 1.7em;
    width: 1.7em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #3264fe;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 3px solid #3264fe;
}
.values{
    background-color: green;
    width: 32%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.values:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid green;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: -14px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Double Range Slider</title>
    <!--Google Fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="values">
            <span id="range1">
                0
            </span>
            <span> &dash; </span>
            <span id="range2">
                100
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="slider-track"></div>
            <input type="range" min="300" max="1500" value="300" id="slider-1" oninput="slideOne()">
            <input type="range" min="300" max="1500" value="1500" id="slider-2" oninput="slideTwo()">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--Script-->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас основная проблемма была в том что у вас slide начинался с 300 и с 1500 и минимальная значение ни как не могло быть `0%`.
Вот на примере, для минимальное значение, у вас 300, ползунок находится на `20%` слева, что не правильно так как у вас ползунок не начинается с 0 а с 300, 300/1500*100 = 20.
Другой вариант решение задать минимальное значение 0 а максимальное 1500, так он будет работать правильно.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  slideOne();
  slideTwo();
}

let sliderOne = document.getElementById("slider-1");
let sliderTwo = document.getElementById("slider-2");
let displayValOne = document.getElementById("range1");
let displayValTwo = document.getElementById("range2");
let minGap = 0;
let sliderTrack = document.querySelector(".slider-track");
let sliderMaxValue = document.getElementById("slider-1").max;

function slideOne() {
  if (parseInt(sliderTwo.value) - parseInt(sliderOne.value) <= minGap) {
    sliderOne.value = parseInt(sliderTwo.value) - minGap;
  }
  displayValOne.textContent = sliderOne.value;
  fillColor();
}

function slideTwo() {
  if (parseInt(sliderTwo.value) - parseInt(sliderOne.value) <= minGap) {
    sliderTwo.value = parseInt(sliderOne.value) + minGap;
  }
  displayValTwo.textContent = sliderTwo.value;
  fillColor();
}

function fillColor() {
  // Тут все изменение, 2 строки, 2 строки Карл)
  percent1 = ((sliderOne.value - 300) / (sliderMaxValue - 300)) * 100;
  percent2 = ((sliderTwo.value - 300) / (sliderMaxValue - 300)) * 100;
  sliderTrack.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #dadae5 ${percent1}% , #3264fe ${percent1}% , #3264fe ${percent2}%, #dadae5 ${percent2}%)`;
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  background-color: #000;
  place-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 95vmin;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 50px 40px 20px 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slider-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 5px;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  height: 5px;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
  appearance: none;
  height: 5px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 1.7em;
  width: 1.7em;
  background-color: #3264fe;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -9px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 1.7em;
  width: 1.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #3264fe;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  height: 1.7em;
  width: 1.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #3264fe;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid #3264fe;
}

.values {
  background-color: green;
  width: 32%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.values:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid green;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: -14px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="values">
      <span id="range1">
                0
            </span>
      <span> &dash; </span>
      <span id="range2">
                100
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slider-track"></div>
      <input type="range" min="300" max="1500" value="300" id="slider-1" oninput="slideOne()">
      <input type="range" min="300" max="1500" value="1500" id="slider-2" oninput="slideTwo()">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```